# python selenium: how to navigate to certain page tab in the web page

Tags: python, selenium

I was doing web scraping for a website with multiple pages in one web page.
But when I click page 2, the url showed http://www.worldhospitaldirectory.com/Germany/hospitals#page-2.

And I put this url as next navigation location. And it goes directly to
http://www.worldhospitaldirectory.com/Germany/hospitals#page-1, which is the default page.

I don't how to navigate to these sub pages.
Any suggestions or code?

my code now:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.worldhospitaldirectory.com/Germany/hospitals')
url = []
pagenbr = 1

while pagenbr <= 43:
   current = driver.current_url
   driver.get(current)
   lks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@href]')
   for ii in lks:
       link = ii.get_attribute('href')
       if '/info' in link:
           url.extend(link)
           print (link)
   print('page ' + str(pagenbr) + ' is done.')
   elm = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next')
   driver.implicitly_wait(10)
   elm.click()
   pagenbr += 1
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that you're using?

Comment: Sure. I will update my code there.@brittenb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just to click appropriate button on pagination as

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next') # to get next page
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('2') # to get second page
```

Comment: I updated my code. It worked on iterate to a new page. But after I iterate to new one. My code cannot pull the links as it did first time. Please give me some advices

Comment: What you expect this line `url.extend(link)` to do? Do you mean `url.append(link)` ?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to change it to append.

Comment: Do you know what is wrong with my code. After it get the links from the first page, it cannot get other links from page 2, 3 and etc.

Comment: What is output of your code? do you get any exceptions, something about `stale element`?

Comment: I need all url of each individual hospitals.http://www.worldhospitaldirectory.com/klinik-fur-anaesthesiologie-und-intensivmedizin/info/4181, this is an example. I can get the first page's 20 links down. But other pages didn't work

Comment: Do you have any idea to fix this problem? It is very hard to load this sub page url.

Comment: Just `import time` and add `time.sleep(2)` after `elm.click()`

Comment: let me try. Thanks for guiding me.

Answer (score 1):

Get element button

```
button_next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class='page-link next'])
button_next.click()
```

I let the algorithm to iterate all pages for you

Comment: Thx, but after I iterate to each new page, i cannot make my loop to pull links from new page. Would you like to take a look? I will update my code now.

Comment: Probably you will have to sleep when click, because script execution is faster than the web load

Comment: yeah, but i put waiting time there to wait for fully loading.

Comment: No, driver.implicitly_wait(10)  is NOT like sleep, is the MAX time to wait functions like find_element to find an element in the web.

Answer (score 0):

## This worked for me

```
while pagenbr <= 3:
    current = driver.current_url
    print current
    driver.get(current)
    lks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@href]')
    for ii in lks:
        link = ii.get_attribute('href')
        if '/info' in link:
            url.extend(link)
            print (link)
    print('page ' + str(pagenbr) + ' is done.')
    elm = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next')
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
 
    elm.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    lks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@href]')
    for ii in lks:
        link = ii.get_attribute('href')
        if '/info' in link:
            url.extend(link)
            print (link)

 
    pagenbr += 1
```